# Setting DefaultValue to first and last date of current month

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I set the `DefaultValue`'s in the following code to the start date *(first ControlParameter)* and last date *(second ControlParameter)* of the current month?

```
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtFromDate" Name="ExpenseDate" PropertyName="Text"
         Type="String" DefaultValue="01-05-2013" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtToDate" Name="ExpenseDate2" PropertyName="Text" 
         Type="String" DefaultValue="30-05-2013" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
</SelectParameters>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
int daysInMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(today.Year, today.Month);

DateTime startOfMonth = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, 1);    
DateTime endOfMonth = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, daysInMonth);
```

Then you can set these values to your controls.

Comment: That's great, glad that I could help!

Answer (score 4):

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
this.txtFromDate.Text = New DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, 1).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");

DateTime lastDayOfMonth = now.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
this.txtToDate.Text = lastDayOfMonth.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

I'm doing this from memory. Sorry for any mistakes or typos, but it's something close to that.

Answer (score 0):

If format of Date Times in your example is correct then this should work:

```
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtFromDate" 
                      Name="ExpenseDate" 
                      PropertyName="Text" 
                      Type="String" 
                      DefaultValue="<%= string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "01-{0:MM-yyyy}", DateTime.Today) %>" 
                      ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtToDate" 
                      Name="ExpenseDate2" 
                      PropertyName="Text" 
                      Type="String" 
                      DefaultValue="<%= string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}-{1:MM-yyyy}", DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month), DateTime.Today) >" 
                      ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
```

Comment: I like this answer better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote myself some extension methods to take care of these scenarios:

```
public static class DateTimeExtensionMethods
{
        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the first day of the month for the given date.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="self">"this" date</param>
        /// <returns>DateTime representing the first day of the month</returns>
        public static DateTime FirstDayOfMonth(this DateTime self)
        {
            return new DateTime(self.Year, self.Month, 1, self.Hour, self.Minute, self.Second, self.Millisecond);
        }   // eo FirstDayOfMonth


        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the last day of the month for the given date.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="self">"this" date</param>
        /// <returns>DateTime representing the last of the month</returns>
        public static DateTime LastDayOfMonth(this DateTime self)
        {
            return FirstDayOfMonth(self.AddMonths(1)).AddDays(-1);
        }   // eo LastDayOfMonth
}
```